# How to mock a Job object in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, jobs

When it comes to Queue testing in Laravel, I use the provided [Queue Fake](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#queue-fake) functionality. However, there is a case where I need to create a Mock for a Job class.

I have the following code that pushes a job to a Redis powered queue:

```
  $apiRequest->storeRequestedData($requestedData); // a db model
  // try-catch block in case the Redis server is down
    try {
        App\Jobs\ProcessRunEndpoint::dispatch($apiRequest)->onQueue('run');
        $apiRequest->markJobQueued();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //handle the case when the job is not pushed to the queue
    }
```

I need to be able to test the code in the catch block. Because of that, I'm trying to mock the Job object in order to be able to create a faker that will throw an exception.

I tried this in my Unit test:

```
   ProcessRunEndpoint::shouldReceive('dispatch');
```

That code returns: `Error: Call to undefined method App\Jobs\ProcessRunEndpoint::shouldReceive()`.
I also tried to swap the job instance with a mock object using `$this->instance()` but it didn't work as well.

That said, how can I test the code in the catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of using a facade for adding a job to the queue (`App\Jobs\ProcessRunEndpoint::dispatch($apiRequest)->onQueue('run');`), I injected it into the action of the controller:

```php
    public function store(ProcessRunEndpoint $processRunEndpoint)
    {
        // try-catch block in case the Redis server is down
        try {
            $processRunEndpoint::dispatch($apiRequest)->onQueue('run');        
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //handle the case when the job is not pushed to the queue
        }
    }
```

With this, the job object is resolved from the container, so it can be mocked:

```php
        $this->mock(ProcessRunEndpoint::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('dispatch')
                ->once()
                ->andThrow(new \Exception());
        });
```

Although still not sure why the `shouldReceive` approach doesn't work for the facade: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-facades

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#queue-fake), you should be able to test jobs through the mocks provided for the Queue.

```php
Queue::assertNothingPushed();
// $apiRequest->storeRequestedData($requestedData);
// Use assertPushedOn($queue, $job, $callback = null) to test your try catch
Queue::assertPushedOn('run', App\Jobs\ProcessRunEndpoint::class, function ($job) {
    // return true or false depending on $job to pass or fail your assertion
});
```

Making the line `App\Jobs\ProcessRunEndpoint::dispatch($apiRequest)->onQueue('run');` throw an exception is a bit complicated. `dispatch()` just returns an object and `onQueue()` is just a setter. No other logic is done there. Instead, we can make everything fail by messing with the configuration.

Instead of `Queue::fake();`, override default queue driver with one that just won't work: `Queue::setDefaultDriver('this-driver-does-not-exist');` This will make every job dispatch fail and throw an `ErrorException`.

Minimalist example:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    try {
        // Job does nothing, the handle method is just sleep(5);
        AJob::dispatch();
        return view('noError');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return view('jobError');
    }
});
```

```php
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Jobs\AJob;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AJobTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function AJobIsDispatched()
    {
        Queue::fake();

        $response = $this->get('/');

        Queue::assertPushed(AJob::class);

        $response->assertViewIs('noError');
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function AJobIsNotDispatched()
    {
        Queue::setDefaultDriver('this-driver-does-not-exist');

        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertViewIs('jobError');
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I already use Queue Fake to test the queues. But, that only tests if a job is pushed to the queue. I need my test to reach the catch block in the example. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: you cannot make the `dispatch()` function fail.

Comment: Actually I've found a bit of a hack to things work, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I solved it in a different way (I will post the answer now). However, your solution is also interesting. Thanks.